# Why I can't enable shared folders in VMWare?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I can't enable shared folders in VMWare 8. Any selections is gray!!
[image: VMWare/vm options/shared folders]

I've tried run as Administrator but it is always GRAY.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The VM must be powered off, not suspended, to change that setting. Boot the VM, then do a proper shutdown inside the VM, you should then be able to change that setting.

Comment: This is not true in current versions of VMware Workstation (at least 8, 9, not sure about older ones).

Comment: This is still true as of Version 15.xx (2019) in case anyone new is wondering!

Answer (score 3):

I know this probably goes without saying, but have you done `VM > Install VMware Tools` from the VMware Workstation menu? VMware Workstation temporarily connects the virtual machine's first virtual CD-ROM drive to the ISO image file that contains the VMware Tools installer for your guest operating system and you are ready to begin the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your VM is configured as a "Shared VM." You need to move it out of the "Shared VM's" folder in VMWare Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Update Vmware tools and enable "Network sharing" - works for me.